# Factory counts 2 models instead of 1 in tests

Tags: laravel, testing, phpunit, laravel-6, laravel-factory

I have these migrations:

```
class CreateOrdersTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        });
    }
}
```

```
class CreatePaymentsTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('payments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('order_id');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('order_id')->references('id')->on('orders');
        });
    }
}
```

and these factories:

```
$factory->define(Payment::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'order_id' => factory(Order::class)->create(),
    ];
});
```

```
$factory->define(Order::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'user_id' => factory(User::class)->create(),
    ];
});
```

Now in my test i have this:

```
/** @test */
public function it_should_count_1_order()
{
     $order = factory(Order::class)->create();

     $payment = factory(Payment::class)->create([
         'order_id' => $order->id,
     ]);

     $this->assertEquals(1, Order::count())
}
```

The Order table count gives me `2`. why? it should be `1` since I am telling payment factory to override `order_id` with the given order. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try defining your factory like this:

```
$factory->define(Order::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'user_id' => factory(User::class),
});
```

If it does not help, make sure you use in your tests `DatabaseTransactions` or `DatabseMigrations` test and you clear database before running test 1st time. Otherwise each time you run test you will be getting more and more records in database.

Personally, I think using  assertion like this:

```
$this->assertEquals(1, Order::count())
```

in tests is not a good idea. You might decide to create some other additional data when you create more advanced test and you should not care about models created before. I personally would like this test like this:

```
$initialOrdersCount = Order::count();

// here you run some actions you want to test

$this->assertSame($initialOrdersCount  + 1, Order::count());
```

This way, in case anything else happens in application or will be added to test, I don't care if I have in database 2 or 3 models. For me it's important that number or orders should be increased by one.

Answer (score 1):

Since your `Payment factory` is creating an `Order`, you Do not need create an `Order` before and pass it to the `Payment factory`.

```
/** @test */
public function it_should_count_1_order()
{
     $payment = factory(Payment::class)->create();

     $this->assertEquals(1, Order::count())
}
```

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. I am still overriding the order_id. why its creating 2 orders instead of 1 ?

Comment: No matter what you do in php, if you define something within an array it has to resolve at some point :)